# Powershel script for install updates on multiple windows servers

Tags: powershell, updates, windows-server

I need a PowerShell script to install updates or security patches

this is my script but its response failed

```
# Check for updates
$updates = Get-WindowsUpdate -Classification "Critical,Security"

# Install updates
Install-WindowsUpdate -KBArticleID $updates.KBArticleID
```

Comment: You need to run As Admin.  Start PS by right click on shortcut and select Run As Admin.

Comment: And if you need to run on multiple machines, you will need [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command) and provide credentials as domain admin

Answer (score 0):

I'd still recommend you to use `PSWindowsUpdate` which is much more reliable.

*Install the module by running the PS as administrator*

```
Install-Module PSWindowsUpdate
```

*Install all the available updates and reboot the system*

```
Get-WindowsUpdate -AcceptAll -Install -AutoReboot
```

*For specific updates*

```
Get-WindowsUpdate -Install -KBArticleID 'KB5021200'
```

You can manually download the module from [PS Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSWindowsUpdate/2.2.0.3) and to learn more about it, you can check [pswindowsupdate - by Adam](https://adamtheautomator.com/pswindowsupdate/)

Comment: I think remotely you have to use the task scheduler options.

Comment: I will still go for `PSSession` and configure `Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts –Value * -Force` first.

Answer (score 0):

Use `-Category` instead of `-Classification` and a loop for installing each update:

```
# Check for updates
$updates = Get-WindowsUpdate -Category "Critical Updates", "Security Updates", "Feature Packs"

# Loop for installing each update
foreach ($update in $updates) {
Get-WindowsUpdate -Install -KBArticleID $update.KBArticleIDs
}
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**